# Is there is any way to get standard field api name from standard report types reports in apex?

Tags: apex, describesobject, reports-api, describefieldresult

I want to get the api name of the standard field being used in Reports of Standard report types. I used describe methods to get the columns used in a report. I analysed some of standard reports containing standard fields(of both standard and custom objects).

I found that Names of those field are not same as API name of the field. For example, For Opportunity's Name I got three names in some of standard reports of Standard report types. These are: `OPP_NAME`, `OPPORTUNITY_NAME`, `OPP.NAME`.

Is there any mapping or something in apex using which i can get the exact field name used in report?

Comment: Chiming in that I'd like to get an answer to this one, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late answer, but hopefully useful.

Cutting short, yes, there is a way. However, I couldn't find, how to do it without callout to [Reports REST API Description](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getbasic_reportmetadata.htm).

```
String reportId = '00O63000001NtWU';

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v51.0/analytics/reports/' + reportId + '/describe');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
Map<String, Object> resBody = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
Map<String, Object> reportExtendedMetadata = (Map<String, Object>) resBody.get('reportExtendedMetadata');
Map<String, Object> detailColumnInfo = (Map<String, Object>) reportExtendedMetadata.get('detailColumnInfo');
for (String key : detailColumnInfo.keySet()) {
    Map<String, Object> tmp = (Map<String, Object>) detailColumnInfo.get(key);
    System.debug(key + ' ' + (String) tmp.get('entityColumnName')); // OPPORTUNITY_NAME Opportunity.Name
}
```

I have also tried to retrieve *reportExtendedMetadata* without callout, but it has less information in *detailColumnInfo* (the core thing it has NO *entityColumnName* info):

```
String reportId = '00O63000001NtWU';
Reports.reportResults body = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);
Reports.ReportExtendedMetadata reportExtendedMetadata = body.getReportExtendedMetadata();
Map<String, Reports.DetailColumn> detailColumnInfo = reportExtendedMetadata.getDetailColumnInfo();

for (String key : detailColumnInfo.keySet()) {
    System.debug(detailColumnInfo.get(key).getName()); // no information about entityColumnName
}
```